# Skip login screen from scene delegate in tabbed bar navigation App

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to skip the login screen and go straight to the MainViewController when the user is logged in. However the problem is that I have a Tab Bar Controller and Navigation Controller between the login and the main vc. After extensive search I wrote the below code

```
 func showMainViewController() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let mainViewController: MainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController


        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)

        //It removes all view controllers from the navigation controller then sets the new root view controller and it pops.
        window?.rootViewController = navigationController

//        //Navigation bar is hidden
//        navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }
```

However it fails to show the tab bar view controller. Any help is appreciated. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
func showMainViewController() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let mainViewController: MainViewController =      storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBar") 

        window?.rootViewController = mainViewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

you should instantiate TabBar no main viewController. since is instantiate inmediatrly is if first index or set the selected index

Comment: Thank you !! It worked properly I had to modify the code however it worked!